# How do i overlay image on card using css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to put small images on `bootstrap` card. Half image will be outside of the card and half image will be inside of the card.

How can fix this?

[image]

Here is my code:-

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="assets/images/images/brush.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>Graphic Desiger</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply have some `custom CSS` to achieve this. Set your `img` to `position absolute`. And some margins to your main `div`

**Demo**

```css
img {
  margin-top: -50px;
  width: 50%;
}

.col-md-4 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10em;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5>Graphic Desiger</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5>Developer</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    </div>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5>Front End</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In case of I have multiple cards than I have to do custom css for all cards... so What I do then?

Comment: @devanshi I have edited my answer. Which shows multiple cards with image.

Comment: @devanshi happy to help. Happy coding :)